# JList of all Filenames in a Folder

Tags: java, string, swing, object, jlist

I'm trying to program a que card application using Swing.
Now I'm trying to list all the que card decks (which are txt files) in one folder in a JList.
So I want to get the filenames of the text files and add them to the list, which I've already created. I tried multiple approaches and this is the closest I think I've gotten:

```
    JList<DeckTypeA> listTypeADecks = new JList();
    DefaultListModel<DeckTypeA> listModelTypeADecks = new DefaultListModel<DeckTypeA>();
    File folder = new File("dexA");


//much later in the code
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            String[] listOfFileNames = new String[listOfFiles.length];
            listOfFileNames[i] = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            listTypeADecks.setListData(listOfFileNames); //here i get an error
          };
```

I get an error message saying that `JList.setListData(String[])` is invalid (I've tried adding it to the default list model and adding it in many different other ways). When I looked up the method it always said that the parameter has to be an object but isn't a string a type of object?
Help would be much appreciated and if you notice anything other mistakes please let me know.

Comment: You are creating a new listOfFileNames array for any file you find in the directory... is that what you want? I'd expect only one listOfFileNames array containing the names of all files. I'm not sure about the JList issue but maybe you could try just setting the array as listData outside of the for-loop, once it's complete.

Comment: Your `listTypeDecks` is `JList<DeckTypeA>`, so its `setListData` expects an array of `DeckTypeA`. You are supplying it an array of `String` - the wrong way, as Dario said, but anyway, that's a type mismatch. You should decide whether you need a list of file names (which is a `JList<String>`, or a `JList<DeckTypeA>`, which means you'll need to provide it with `DeckTypeA` objects to display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

- You're declaring `listofFileNames` **inside** the `for`-loop. This variable is initialized every loop again and *destroyed* at the end. This means any changes are thrown away.
- You're calling `listTypeADecks.setListData` at the end of each loop, but you probably want to call it after the whole loop when it's complete.
- In your implementation there will be empty `Strings` in `listOfFileNames` since not every index may be a file, but you just skip them.

You probably want something like this:

```
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    List<String> listOfFileNames = new List<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            listOfFileNames.add(listOfFiles[i].getName());
          };
    listTypeADecks.setListData(listOfFileNames.toArray());
```